# Frames not switching by index number

Tags: selenium, iframe

I took no. of frames as 'frsize' and started loop for switching frames by index. but it's not switching to another index.

```
 Boolean flag=null;
 List<WebElement> frames=driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
 int frsize=frames.size();

 for(int i=0;i<frsize;i++) 
 {
  driver.switchTo().frame(i);
  System.out.println("Frame Index Number "+i);
  flag = driver.findElements(By.xpath(locatorValue)).size()!= 0;
  System.out.println("Checking Flag Condition");
  if(flag==true)
  {
   System.out.println("It returns true");
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("It returns false");
   return false;
  }
 }
```

After switching 1st frame It's not entering to 2nd frame. It terminated for loop and no exceptions.

Here is the actual output

Frame Index Number 0
Checking Flag Condition
It returns false
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 134.152 sec

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

Add `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` as a last step in your for loop. So that always the context will change to parent then to the iframe with in the loop.

```
 Boolean flag=null;
 List<WebElement> frames=driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
 int frsize=frames.size();

 for(int i=0;i<frsize;i++) 
 {
  driver.switchTo().frame(i);
  System.out.println("Frame Index Number "+i);
  flag = driver.findElements(By.xpath(locatorValue)).size()!= 0;
  System.out.println("Checking Flag Condition");
  if(flag==true)
  {
   System.out.println("It returns true");
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("It returns false");
   return false;
  }
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 }
```

Comment: If  `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` does not work then use `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();`.

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the down vote button on the left hand side in my answer. Feel free to upvote :-)

Comment: sorry, It removes error but still not working. It terminating for loop

Comment: what is your frsize? And are you sure the locatorvalue is correct? If I am not wrong you might have only one frame?

Comment: Locator value is correct. I verified it and there are 3 frames in that page.  I'm pasting my output here.

Number of Frames are: 3

Frame Index Number 0
Checking Flag Condition
It returns false
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 92.277 sec

Comment: Cool! What was the root cause?  how did you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with pop-up dialog/iframe windows within your webpage, then `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` is used to switch the control back to default content in the window.

Comment: sorry, It removes error but still not working. It terminating for loop